# Entity Framework 4.1 - How to get a name of a column for a generated poco object

Tags: .net, entity-framework, poco

I am using entity framework 4.1, an edmx mapping file is used to generate poco classes using T4 templates.

How can I get a name of the data base column out of object context for my poco entity properties (if it is possible at all).

I believe the mapping between properties and columns should be in one of the containers:

```
var container = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace
    .GetEntityContainer(objectContext.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);
...
```

But I was not able to identify a link between CSpase and SSpace, it looks like CSSpase might do the job, but this container is empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: CSSpace is entirely internalized. You'll need to do non public member reflection or read the raw csspace xml to get the info you need.

Comment: I can read edmx file, but this is something I would like to avoid. Do you have an example of how to hack into CSSpace?

Comment: I used to take the non public reflection route, but things started to break with differences in data models. I ended up abandoning it in favor of the xml route which is slightly less of a hack (I guess). You don't need to read the edmx itself. The edmx is embedded in your output assembly as three manifest resources (an ssdl, csdl, and msl)....so you can load the xml right from those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a mixed approached to get the mapping information (we have to implement custom data reader/writer for certain types):

1. First get EntityType object to extract meta information for your POCO type:

   ```
   public static EntityType GetEntityTypeForPoco(this ObjectContext context, 
                                                            Type pocoEntityType)
   {
       EntityType entityType 
                = context.MetadataWorkspace.GetItem<EntityType>
                  (pocoEntityType.FullName, DataSpace.OSpace);

       return (EntityType)context.MetadataWorkspace
              .GetEdmSpaceType((StructuralType)entityType);
   }
   ```
2. Read mapping XML document: this part is basically hardcoded, mapping xml document is saved in the assembly where edmx file is, it's called **[your_edmx_file_name].msl**

   ```
   currentMslSchemaDocument = new StreamReader(
               Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().
               GetManifestResourceStream(CurrentMslSchemaDocumentName)
             ).ReadToEnd();
   ```
3. Read property to column mapping from XML document:

   ```
   var mappingFragments = MslSchemaDocument
   .Descendants(XName.Get(ElementNameEntityTypeMapping, NamespaceNameMsl))
   .Where(mp => (mp.Attributes(AttributeNameTypeName).Any() 
   && mp.Attribute(AttributeNameTypeName).Value == entityTypeModelName));

   if (mappingFragments.Count() == 0)
   {
       throw new Exception(String.Format("Entity mapping {0} is not found in the given schema stream", entityTypeModelName));
   }

   //theoretically could be several fragments mapping one entity ytpe to several table
   XElement mappingFragment = mappingFragments.First();

   string tableName = mappingFragment.Descendants(XName.Get(ElementNameMappingFragment, NamespaceNameMsl))
   .First().Attribute(AttributeNameStoreEntitySet).Value;

   List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> propertyColumnMappingList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

   foreach (var xScalarProperty in mappingFragment.Descendants(XName.Get(ElementNameScalarProperty, NamespaceNameMsl)))
   {
      propertyColumnMappingList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(xScalarProperty.Attribute(AttributeNameName).Value,
               xScalarProperty.Attribute(AttributeNameColumnName).Value));
   }
   ```

Comment: I find it ridiculous that one needs to jump through so much hoops, just to get some basic mapping info that EF uses all along the route. 2 years have passed now. I'm curious if anything has changed.

Comment: As far as I know not yet, they (microsoft) has promised to make it available as a part of API, maybe will come with a new version of dev tools. But honestly I am not tracing the issue anymore, the existing code works, meaning library interfaces and behavior are more or less the same.